# iOS 15 Safari - How do you detect tab bar or single tab selection programmatically?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

Is there a way to determine whether a user has selected the Tab Bar or the Single Tab for iOS 15 Safari programmatically with Javascript or HTML or CSS? I am running into [the viewport hidden issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974702/ios-15-safari-detect-floating-address-bar-when-keyboard-is-visible) and until Apple rolls out an official fix, I would like to write a fix that targets browsers for the tab bar only.
[Safari Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVq6P.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.